# Resolve container name in extra_hosts option in docker-compose

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose

I need to curl my API from another container.
Container 1 is called `nginx`
Container 2 is called `fpm`

I need to by able to bash into my `fpm` container and curl the `nginx` container.

Config:

```yaml
#docker-compose.yaml
services:
 
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/conf/dev/api.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - fpm
    
    
  fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/fpm/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/fpm/conf/dev/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
      - ./docker/fpm/conf/dev/api.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/api.ini
    env_file:
      - ./docker/mysql/mysql.env
      - ./docker/fpm/conf/dev/fpm.env
    links:
      - mysql
    shm_size: 256M
    extra_hosts:
      - myapi.docker:nginx
```

My initial thought was to slap it in the `extra_hosts` option like:

```
extra_hosts:
  - myapi.docker:nginx
```

But docker-compose up fails with:

> ERROR: for apiwip_fpm_1  Cannot create container for service fpm: invalid IP address in add-host: "nginx"

I have seen some examples of people using docker's network configuration but it seems over the top to just resolve an address.

How can I resolve/eval the IP address of the container rather than just passing it literally?

Comment: Did you ever got this working?

Comment: no, i ended up just passing in the IP address, or by just setting and extra_host to match my virtual server (or localhost)

Comment: Just a note - the error message comes from the fact that the `extra_hosts` parameter is used incorrectly - the values should be in the format `<host>:<ip_address>` - see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts . Therefore, the `nginx` is taken to be an IP address.

Comment: The link in @piit79's comment has changed and is now https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#extra_hosts (for v3)

Comment: @Gorgsenegger first job back after the new year to play with docker networks? I don't envy you. Lol Thanks for the link update.

Comment: @Edward yes, you're right. Things could be worse, though, was a minor detail I needed to look up in the docs ;-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add **network aliases** in the default network.

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  nginx:
    # ...
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - example.local

  browser-sync:
    # ...
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    command: "browser-sync start --proxy http://example.local"
```

Comment: I was trying to create an alias with `domainname`, but your snippet did the trick

Answer (score 12):

```yaml
services:
  nginx:
    build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/conf/dev/api.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      my_network:
        aliases:
          - myapi.docker
          - docker_my_network
  fpm:
    build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./docker/fpm/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/fpm/conf/dev/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
      - ./docker/fpm/conf/dev/api.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/api.ini
    env_file:
      - ./docker/mysql/mysql.env
      - ./docker/fpm/conf/dev/fpm.env
    links:
      - mysql
    shm_size: 256M
    networks:
      - my_network

  networks:
    my_network:
      driver: bridge
```

- add custom network and add container to that network
- by default if you curl nginx container from fpm you will curl localhost, so we need to add alias to be the same as your servername in the nginx configuration
- with this solution you can curl myapi.docker from the fpm container

@edward let me know if this solution worked for you

Edit:
Jack_Hu is right, I removed extra_hosts. Network alias is enough.

Comment: Nice. this looks like it could work. next time i work on this project i will let you know pal, thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Still get the original error: `ERROR: for apiwip_fpm_1 Cannot create container for service fpm: invalid IP address in add-host: "nginx"`

Comment: Solved it... The solution is to COMPLETELY REMOVE THE `extra_hosts:` `- myapi.docker:nginx` bit from the above. The network alias is effectively replacing it, and rather than the DNS being resolved in the `/etc/hosts` file, it's instead being resolved on the virtual network adaptor itself... Basically, because a service has been given an alias on a given network, every other service that's also on that network is able to resolve the given alias to the service it's attached to.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this kind of issue by using `links` instead of `extra_hosts`.

In that case, just set `link alias` can do your favor.

*service fpm setting*

```
links
  - nginx:myapi.docker
```

See [docker-compose links documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links), The alias name can be the domain which appears in your code.

Comment: `link` has been deprecated for quite a while now. Network alias's should be used instead. See Denis Kovacevic's answer, and my comments to it for details.

Answer (score 3):

From the docker documentation,

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

You should be able to use your service name (in this case `nginx`) as a hostname from within your docker network. So you can bash into my FPM container and call `curl nginx` and the docker will resolve it for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: i need an alias in `/etc/hosts` really, but ill have a look thanks mate

Comment: means you'll clutter containers with incidental details for features like internal SSL termination and complicate any non-TLS setup

Answer (score -5):

Quick fix is to point it to a dynamic IP generated by docker. This may change though so... yeah.

Find your networks:
`docker network ls`

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                 DRIVER              SCOPE
72fef1ce7a50        apiwip_default       bridge              local <-- here
cdf9d5b885f6        bridge               bridge              local
2f4f1e7038fa        host                 host                local
a96919eea0f7        mgadmin_default      bridge              local
30386c421b70        none                 null                local
5457b953fadc        website2_default     bridge              local
1450ebeb9856        anotherapi_default   bridge              local
```

Copy the NETWORK ID

`docker network inspect 72fef1ce7a50`

```
"Containers": {
            "345026453e1390528b2bb7eac4c66160750081d78a77ac152a912f3de5fd912c": {
                "Name": "apiwip_nginx_1",
                "EndpointID": "6504a3e4714a6ba599ec882b21f956bfd1b1b7d19b8e04772abaa89c02b1a686",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.5/16", <-- CIDR block
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ea89d3089193825209d0e23c8105312e3df7ad1bea6b915ec9f9325dfd11736c": {
                "Name": "apiwip_fpm_1",
                "EndpointID": "dc4ecc7f0706c0586cc39dbf8a05abc9cc70784f2d44c90de2e8dbdc9148a294",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```

Add the IP address from that CIDR block to the extra_hosts option:

```
extra_hosts:
  - myapi.docker:172.20.0.5
```

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: would not prefer this "solution", which is very fragile, as already described in the introductory sentence of the Post

Comment: Hi guys, just in case it wasn't clear this is not a solution (i didn't mark this as such either). if you want a solution feel free to try the other answers and leave a comment, thanks.

Comment: upvoted since it gives some perspective to troubleshooting and helped to find container not having been attached to the network, thanks